# Running Java application in Android VMware

Tags: java, android, vmware

I am trying to see the result of running my Java application on a phone based on Android OS.

So I was wondering, is it possible to use VMware and then using the Android-x86 2.2 live & installation iso to run it in VMware and then running my app in Android system?

Comment: I would suggest using the emulator from the Android SDK instead. VMware/Virtualbox have significant hardware differences from a phone, with the available screen estate being the major one - you just can't get a proper feel of a phone-based application on a screen with the resolution and aspect ratio of a computer display. Having a different CPU platform might also be important if you are using native libraries.

Comment: @thkala i see, lets have a look at it too.

Comment: @thkala i downloaded the sdk and tried to get through it, but still dont know how to rub my Client-server java application on it

Answer (score 3):

Folks.  Why am I being down voted?  I've worked hard to help people out and gain rep.  So the question might not be good for SO, but I helped someone out with something that works.  Seems harsh to lose rep over it....

Yes! :)

http://geeknizer.com/how-to-run-google-android-in-virtualbox-vmware-on-netbooks/

http://androiddevnotes.com/2011/03/08/1299521520000.html

I use it a lot and it's much faster than the emulator.  I recommend using the generic x86 iso and creating a virtual machine rather than using the live iso.  That way, you can configure all kinds of things, snapshot it etc..

Comment: then what are the down votes for my question and your answer?

Comment: but the thing i want to run is my java app in android. just wondering if by running android on a vMware, it gives the ability to run my java app there too

Comment: I didn't down vote either but a question like this where there isn't a problem, not a lot of research and very open ended goes against what SO is about.

Comment: You're using Eclipse or IDEA right?  And you want to run/debug your app with the Android virtual machine as a target?  Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @Simon yea, im using Netbeans IDE and wanna run my application under android virtual matchine

Comment: Just look at the links I sent, they'll tell you what you need.  Just run adb connect 192.168.140.1 (or whatever the IP address of the VM is) to use it for debugging.

Comment: @Simon ok, let me have a look at try then :)